# Logic related to Cantor's argument

Tags: logic

Suppose we construct a choice function that separates R/{0} in the interval (0,1) (viewed in base 2) into two sets A and B each consisting of an arbitrary element chosen from every pair of complements. Suppose then that we map all the elements of B to 0, while each element of the other set A are mapped to an element of 1,2,3,…. Members of R/{0} sent to 0 are identified with an element not in the set R/{0}, hence not in 1,2,3,…while those in A are mapped to elements of 1,2,3... Can we formally decide whether set A is diagonalizable or not?

Comment: I made an edit to focus the question on Gaifman's argument. You may roll this back or continue editing it. Hopefully the reference to Gaifman will focus the question you are asking.  Welcome to this SE!

Comment: It's not a proof by contradiction. Period. Given an arbitrary list of real numbers, there is some real number not on it. That's stated and proved directly. Not contradiction. Not contradiction. Happy to debunk this common misunderstanding. Did I mention it's not a proof by contradiction?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you are asking "IF" we could construct a set with the property that we could not formally decide whether it is diagonalisable or not, then would this invalidate the diagonal argument as applied by Cantor.  Yes.  It would say that the predicate "is diagonalisable" is not a classical predicate since it would not obey the law of the excluded middle and therefore it has no place in any argument using classical logic.

Comment: ....  Having said that, the construction you give in support of your question is not at all clear.  For example, it would be helpful if you could clarify what you mean by "Pair set B with 0 and list the members of set A paired with the natural numbers."  Also, the sets {x 1-x} would not be equivalence classes.

Comment: "is it not necessary that his argument method (diagonalization) hold for all forms of the argument in any number base ?" NO. The proof assumes that we have a listing of **all** real numbers and the diagonal method shows how to produce a real number **not** in the list. Conclusion ; the list is not a list of **all** real numbers.

Comment: user4894-Thank you for your reply. Whether you want to see it as not a proof by contradiction or not, it is the construction that is called into question here...for the construction I have made reference to (sets A and B) there is no proof of the existence of "some real number not on it." The complement of the diagonal cannot be shown to not be on the list I have assigned to B....it does not have to be on A to have failed to give a map from N to a set equinumerous with R. Again, I am not saying that this is a proof that N and R are equinumerous...just that there is a hole in Cantor's argument.

Comment: Nick R- they are equivalence classes for the relation : complements... elements of each class are complements of each other.

Comment: Mauro- The proof proceeds by a claim that there is no map from N to R such that the number of elements matches...it relies on pairing, then attempting to show such a pairing must fail. There is a requirement  for a full contradiction: all possible pairings both direct and indirect must fail or it is possible that the non-failure of any reveals that there is at least one implicit assumption that must be dealt with. The implicit assumption in every version of the fixed point theorem/diagonalization regarding the reals assumes you must have a direct mapping...not so.

Comment: Mauro- The sets A and B are equinumerous with R. To draw the desired conclusion they too must be shown to fail the diagonalization step, otherwise there is a path to a mapping that escapes the conclusion.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Hubeny...I appreciate with your edit.

Comment: The "implicit assumption" isn't implicit at all, it is a definition of ZFC: every mapping has to be a set of pairs, explicitly. If one is unhappy with it, like Poincare and intuitionists, one does not need to make it, and the diagonal argument does not go through. That too is well known. So what exactly is the question here?

Comment: Conifold- you might just think of it this way..it is a composite mapping...N to A, A to R, hence still a mapping...N is paired with A, then A with R.  I am certain that idea is quite mainstream in mathematics and OK in ZFC. Transitive relations are allowed. The task of a proof that N is not equinumerous with R must deal with such a mapping.

Comment: It makes no difference which way you think of it. Any map however defined is provably equivalent in ZFC to an explicit set of pairs, or it is not a map, by definition. Your distinction, and argument based on it confuse, internal and external languages. You can object from outside of ZFC based on this distinction, but within ZFC it can not even be expressed. So accept ZFC or don't, either way there is nothing new here.

Comment: It's a nitpicky point, but an equivalence relation must be reflexive, symmetric, and transitive.  The relation underlying {x, 1-x} on [0,1] is  aEb if and only if a+b=1.  This relation is neither reflexive nor transitive, so the corresponding classes are not equivalence classes.  It doesn't really matter since it is not really used in your argument.

Comment: Conifold- Thank you for your comments. I re-read this paper by Paul Cohen... 
 https://www.math.upenn.edu/~kazdan/proof/notes/Proof2005-PJCohen-2407-18.pdf , and I think I have a better idea of what I am thinking in relation to ZFC and the Skolem-Lowenhiem Theorem regarding inner and outer models.

Comment: Nick R- I understood the ideas of a partition and a set of equivalence classes as essentially the same. I suppose the classes of complements are classes with one element...the pair of complements. certainly R can be partitioned into complementary pairs. I added an edit to my OP.

Comment: So I voted to close as "unclear what you're asking". This question is entirely too long. This happens a lot when people have questions that seem either controversial or are questioning really technical results, you write out a super long detailed question and then people engage you in the comments and you just go and add more and more to the already too long question. I have been there for the beginning of questions like this and have seen it unfold many times. Coming to this question late, after all of the added text, it is just too long and disorganized to be agreeable.

Comment: I would suggest completely rewriting the question, making what you are actually asking concise instead of just adding more and more extra points to address what was said in the comments. I can't look at what you wrote and easily figure out what your main question is, and questions on this site are supposed to be one single question per post, so that is a huge issue. I understand what you're asking is technical, but right now this question needs to be salvaged by editing and pruning unnecessary information that is muddling the main question.

Comment: Not_Here-OK I'll try to pare it down.

Comment: Nick R- I just re-read your first comment...the big "IF" is exactly what I am claiming...this mapping is undecidable...sorry I missed that.

Comment: If you are "sending every element of set B to 0" then you do not have a 1-1 map. The diagonal argument does not apply to any maps whatsoever, but only to 1-1 maps between N and R, assuming there are any. The diagonal argument shows that there are none.

Comment: This question is still disorganized and muddled, I am really disappointed that it was reopened and I am going to open up a discussion about it on meta. As an example of how it's still failing, first of all, the first sentence of the last giant block of a paragraph is missing a closed parenthesis so the sentence makes no sense. Second of all, you still do not have a clear and concise statement of your question. You spend the first four paragraphs going into irrelevant background information without having introduced the topic of your question, that is not good for readability.

Comment: You should be able to easily state your question without 1) going over a ton of irrelevant background information that led you to the question and 2) a block paragraph of arguments setting up the question. Those two things are okay, to a moderate extend, *after* you clearly and concisely state your question, but this still reads like a run on train of thought and not a well presented question.

Comment: [Meta post here](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3765/should-this-question-have-been-reopened)

Comment: I have further edited the question by eliminating all of the initial info relating to context and added the clarification of my question suggested by Nick R (for that clarification I am grateful, thanks)...I left the bold italics so that a reader can easily skip the above and see the question. It seems to me that it would not make sense to ask the question without any context.

Comment: Just so you are aware, I up voted your question early on and I did not down vote it.

Comment: Thank you. I hoped for nothing more than a fair hearing, so to speak.

Comment: Mr. Hubeny- I have learned a lot already from the little interaction I have had at this site. I did not ask the question to incite controversy, but rather to refine my grip on logic in general and this question in particular.

Answer (score 1):

The diagonalization is a way of finding a real number that is not on a given ordered list of real numbers.  In your example, given your A, we can find a real number that is not on the list of A.  We don't know if it's in B, and it doesn't matter.  The theorem is that we can find a real number not on any ordered/countable list of real numbers.  It doesn't say that, given a list A of real numbers, that we can produce a real that isn't in list A or B.  If there were a 1-1 correspondence between reals and natural numbers, we could produce an ordered list of all reals, but there is at least one real number not on the list.  This is a constructive proof that leads to a proof by contradiction.

Also, Sets A and B are not equinumerous with R.  Since the reals in set A can be put into 1-1 correspondence with the natural numbers, and also can be put into 1-1 correspondence with members of set B, then they're countable, and R isn't.  If A is equinumerous with R, it's not possible to have a 1-1 correspondence with the natural numbers.  You have chosen a countable subset of R, and are trying to prove it's countable, which doesn't prove anything.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Thornley. If we have a 1-to-1 mapping from set A to R and list the elements of A, yet cannot show we arrive at a contradiction, then there exists a possible mapping that has not been shown to lead to contradiction. The fact that it has not been shown to be impossible to go from N to A to R indicates that we have not eliminated the possibility of the existence of such a map. Such a map would provide a case of N being equinumerous with R. I am not saying this proves there is such a map, just that we do not have a proof that there is not....that is what Cantor's purports to be.

Comment: Mr Thornley...regarding your second paragraph: how do we know sets A and B are not equinumerous with R? Please explain. You also claim they can be put into a 1-1 correspondence with N, is there a proof of that?

Comment: It may be possible to go from N to A or A to R with 1-1 maps, but Cantor's original proof (which you have not shown invalid) shows that it's not possible to go from N to R.  Your statement "the other complement to an element of N" suggests 1-1, and, in any case, if no  element of N is mapped to an uncountable number of reals we can make a mapping 1-1.  If the mapping isn't 1-1 to N (or at least can't be made to be) then we can't do the diagonalization in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia outlines Cantor's diagonal argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument). Cantor used binary digits in his 1891 proof so using "base 2 representations of the Reals" work in the argument:

> In his 1891 article, Cantor considered the set *T* of all infinite sequences of binary digits (i.e. each digit is zero or one). He begins with a constructive proof of the following theorem:
>
> If s<sub>1</sub>, s<sub>2</sub>, … , s<sub>n</sub>, … is any enumeration of elements from *T*, then there is always an element *s* of *T* which corresponds to no s<sub>n</sub> in the enumeration.

Note that the proof starts by considering *any enumeration* of these sequences of binary digits which can represent the real numbers.  In particular this would include the specific enumeration suggested by the OP:

> Form two subsets of R[0,1] by choosing arbitrary members of each class, sending one such member of each class to set A and the other to set B. Pair set B with 0 and list the members of set A paired with the natural numbers. Do we not get an arrangement of A and N for which the diagonal argument does not lead to contradiction?  For when we try to argue that if we take the diagonal of the N vs. A arrangement and attempt to argue that its complement is not accounted for...it cannot be proved that it is not in B.

Although there are two lists, A and B, one containing the complement of the other, these two lists could be interleaved so that one has one list. An easy way to get this interleaving is to use odd natural numbers for list A and even natural numbers for list B.

That one list is all we would need to create a sequence of binary digits that could not be in either of the two lists using the diagonal method. Hence the diagonal argument would work with this enumeration as well.

Also one is not taking the complement of all of the binary digits in each sequence associated with a natural number, but only the single binary digit on the diagonal. Only one digit is changed in each sequence of binary digits. That's what makes this argument work. That sequence of binary digits from the diagonal is different from any of the sequences paired with the natural numbers by at least one digit, the one on the diagonal.

The existence of that diagonal sequence of binary digits (or digits in any base) would be evidence that the assumed one-to-one mapping of the reals with the natural numbers is not complete. And so there are more real numbers than the natural numbers can enumerate.

---

The following represents edits to the original question as of 10/20/2018.

The question is:

> I argue that it is necessary that the author of the diagonal argument show how any and all assumed maps lead to contradiction (without changing the assumed mapping) or the argument fails to be decidable...is this logic incorrect, if so, how?

The particular map is the following:

> So I asked can we construct within ZFC a choice function that separates R/{0} in the interval (0,1) (viewed in base 2) into two sets A and B each consisting of an arbitrary element chosen from every pair of complements where information about one of them is completely inaccessible. I thought in this way: by the Axiom of Regularity every non-empty set S contains an element y disjoint from S (essentially a least element). So let’s identify one arbitrary element of each complementary pair of R/{0} in the interval (0,1) with one such element y from outside the set R/{0} …as in sending every element of set B to 0, and elements of the other set A to an element of 1,2,3,…. Then we get an arrangement where those members of R/{0} sent to 0 are identified with an element not in the set R/{0}, hence not in 1,2,3,…while those in A are mapped to elements of 1,2,3...yet the two sets A and B are separately equinumerous with R/{0}. So even though we can view R/{0} as representing the power set of N (aside from the empty set which logically could be paired with the excluded 0), do we get a contradiction via a diagonal argument?

To summarize, assume there exists a choice function that splits the set of real numbers into two sets *A* and *B*. The elements in *B* are the binary complements of the elements in *A*. Assume there is an enumeration, that is, a one-to-one map, between *A* and the natural numbers *N*. Make no assumption about *B* and *N*. The diagonal argument will produce a real number, call it *r*, that is not in *A* by Cantor's argument. However, we have no guarantee that *r* is not somewhere in *B*.

The claim is this provides an example showing that not all mappings between the reals and natural numbers lead to a contradiction.

Let's review the theorem Cantor was trying to prove from Wikipedia:

> If s<sub>1</sub>, s<sub>2</sub>, … , s<sub>n</sub>, … is any enumeration of elements from *T*, then there is always an element *s* of *T* which corresponds to no s<sub>n</sub> in the enumeration.

Note that *T* is the set "of all infinite sequences of binary digits (i.e. each digit is zero or one)". *T* is the set of real numbers.

Note that an "enumeration of elements from *T*" is a one-to-one mapping of the elements of *T* to the natural numbers.

Note that the theorem Cantor is attempting to prove applies to "any enumeration".  It does not apply to any mapping whatsoever.

Since the example of the map of the set *A* of real numbers to *N* is not an enumeration of all the reals, that is, it is not a one-to-one mapping of the real numbers to the natural numbers, it is not one of the mappings that Cantor's theorem is considering.

There are many mappings that Cantor's theorem is not interested in considering. For example, consider the mapping that takes all of the real numbers to the set {1}, the set containing only the natural number 1. This mapping does not usefully help compare the number of real numbers with the number of elements in {1}. Since Cantor is interested in mappings that allow him to compare the number of elements between two sets he would only use one-to-one mappings, enumerations, assuming they exist, not any mappings whatsoever.

---

The OP's question asks: "is this logic incorrect, if so, how?"

The logic is incorrect because it replaces Cantor's original premise about "any enumeration" with "any mapping" and then argues against the new premise as if it were Cantor's. This would be similar to setting up a straw man argument.

---

Reference

Wikipedia, "Cantor's diagonal argument" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument

Comment: Thank you Mr Hubeny...yes, I see, a pair of equinumerous subsets of N will defeat any effort to challenge Cantor's argument via equinumerous subsets of R. Perhaps that is why I have never seen such a challenge in anything I have read. As you say it is easy to get an interleaving.

Comment: I added an edit to my original post...I would be interested in hearing your thoughts.

Comment: @21stCenturyParadox There may be other approaches to the real numbers worth considering. Regarding the Liar paradox, I am interested in logical systems that do not permit the law of the excluded middle except for propositions where one can derive the proposition. See Fitch's *Symbolic Logic*. The linked papers by Bohm and others look interesting. I hope you keep bringing up questions here. Make them very specific, perhaps ones you almost have an answer for. Many questions may lead to a better overall insight after they have been asked. Best wishes.

Comment: Thank you Mr Hubeny...unfortunately the question has been put on hold...I reworked it to give it a better focus. After consideration I have a reply to your idea regarding changing the mapping sending A to odds and B to evens...that idea misses my point. I claim we can exhibit a mapping that is undecidable...changing the mapping does not address that claim. Please see Nick R's comment at the top.

Comment: @21stCenturyParadox You can always ask a different, more specific question. Don't worry that it has been closed. I agree with Nick R's comment. However, I don't think you have a mapping that shows we cannot answer the question whether the diagonal approach works. The assumption is that the reals are countable. So, they can be placed in a 1-1 mapping with the natural numbers. Whatever mapping you come up with has to be a 1-1 mapping with the natural numbers. If many reals can be mapped to 0 in set B, that would not be a 1-1 mapping, but a many to 1 mapping. So it would not work.

Comment: @21stCenturyParadox Also we may be able to discuss this further in a chat room. I usually check this one: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76868/free-will-omnipotence-determinism  Just put an @ in front of my name to send me a message from there.

Comment: Mr Hubeny- Do you mean I should submit a separate version of my question as opposed to the edit I have done?

Comment: OK I will try that, however, I must let this go for 2 hours...I am working....I can return between 1 and 1:30 pm. I will try the chat room then.

Comment: @21stCenturyParadox Yes, but not right away and not the same question. A similar question will be closed just as this one was. Pick very specific topics that should be able to be answered, but which clarify something of interest to you.

Comment: I see the chat rooms have specific topics associated with them...how do you discuss a topic not shown in a chat room?

Comment: I just now read the instructions immediately above the entry box...OK

Comment: I It says I do not have enough rep. points to go to chat. Thank you, I will wait until such time as I do.

Comment: @21stCenturyParadox I see. You may have to try answering a question or asking another. As you get up-votes you will have the permission needed to use the chat feature. It might be worth looking at the tags and seeing which ones are interesting.